# tmux split-window using shell script

Tags: shell, tmux

I am trying to write shell script for creating panes in tmux.

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux rename-window user
tmux new-session -d
tmux split-window -h
tmux selectp -t 1
tmux split-window -h
tmux select-layout even-horizontal
tmux selectp -t 2
tmux split-window -v
```

But when executing the above code doesn't produce desired output.

The picture indicates output produced when the code is executed:

[image: Resulting output]

Instead when all the commands are written in tmux it produces the desired output.

The picture indicates output produced when commands are manually typed:

[image: Desired output]

How can the code be modified to produce the desired outcome?

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it looks like it does what you need (judging by the "Desired Output" image):

```
tmux split-window -h
tmux split-window -h
tmux select-layout even-horizontal
tmux split-window -v
tmux select-pane -t 0
```

You can also try persisting your layout using something like https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't give the required layout. Sure, I'll try the plugin but is there any way to do it in shell script?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute all the `tmux` commands in a single invocation:

```
tmux new-session -d \; split-window -h \; split-window -h\; split-window -v
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh_list=( `cat $1` )
split_list=()
round=0
i=0
for ssh_entry in "${ssh_list[@]:1}"; do
        if (( $((round%2)) == 0 ))
        then
                split_list+=( split-window -v -t $((2*i)) -p 50 ssh "$ssh_entry" ';' )
        else
                split_list+=( split-window -h -t $((2*i)) -p 50 ssh "$ssh_entry" ';' )
        fi
        mxrd=$((2**round))
        i=$((i+1))
        if ((round==0)) || ((i>=mxrd))
        then
                i=0
                round=$((round+1))
        fi
done

tmux new-session ssh "${ssh_list[0]}" ';' \
    select-layout tiled ';' \
    "${split_list[@]}" \
    set-option -w synchronize-panes
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.